# Can you heart a YouTube comment via YouTube API Data v3?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am able to retrieve and like the comments.

However I couldn't find a way to heart the comment.

Still not possible via API?

Answer (score 0):

Simply, it's not possible. YouTube APIs are very well documented, and such a feature does not exist in relative docs. That's because giving a developer an endpoint for that will open the door to some sort of *like-bots*, making all comment system misleading and useless for entire community.

Comment: I don't agree with you concerning the fact that they don't do it because of *like-bots*, as [subscribing to a channel](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/insert) and [liking a video](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/rate) is possible through YouTube Data API v3. They just don't add API access to new features (see [revision history](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/revision_history)).

Comment: @BenjaminLoison thanks for clarifying. You are absolutely right.